# How old is Treebeard?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, magical-creatures, age

We know for certain (from Gandalf) that Treebeard the Ent is the oldest living creature on Middle Earth:

> "Treebeard is Fangorn, the guardian of the forest; he is the oldest of the Ents, the oldest living thing that still walks beneath the Sun upon this Middle-Earth."
> <sub>*TLOTR* Book 3, Chapter 5: *The White Rider*</sub>
> "Treebeard is Fangorn, and the eldest and chief of the Ents, and when you speak with him you will hear the speech of the oldest of all living things." 
>    <sub>*TLOTR* Book 3, Chapter 8: *The Road to Isengard*</sub>

But just how old is he? Obviously somewhere in the thousands of years, but I'm really curious to know exactly how old the oldest (and probably wisest) living creature in Middle-Earth is. Ent eyes are very deep, and Treebeard's eyes the deepest of all. How long have they seen?

Comment: I always wondered about that line.  Based on the Silmarilion I always thought Galadriel was older than Fangorn.

Comment: I would say the Fangorn predates her by a good 5,000 years or so.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/ Who's older: Treebeard or Tom Bombadil?

Comment: @SteveED - Treebeard seems to think that all Elves, even Galadriel, are young whippersnappers, relative to himself.  And Gandalf refers to Treebeard as "the oldest of all living things", and he doesn't make any exceptions to that - even for the Elves.

Comment: Gandalf was wrong. Because Bombadil, who as ever is the wild card.

Comment: @MikeScott But is Bombadil a “living thing”? That's the question…

Comment: Worth noting that according to Christopher Tolkien, his father was given to ’rhetorical superlatives’, such as ’the oldest living thing’.

Comment: Gandalf was more wrong. Galadriel is older.

Comment: Gandalf is older. He was one of the Maia, as well as Sauron and Saruman. They were created before any of the races of middle-earth, after only the Valar, the race of gods first created. It’s all in the Silmarillion...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looking at the timeline from [The Lord of the Rings Wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda), it looks like the time before the first age lasted around 18,000 solar years, and the Ents were created sometime early on in this period.

There also looks to have been at least 10,000 years after the Ents were created.

The First Age lasted about 590 years, the Second Age 3441 years and the LotR took place in 3018 of the Third Age.

So, **17,000 - 25,000 years**, give or take.

Answer (score 5):

well, Gandalf says he has wandered the earth for 300 ages of men. now, if we assume the average age is somewhere between 60 and 80 years, Gandalf is at the most 24.000 years old. Treebeard greets him, in The Return of the King, as "young master Gandalf"...

Comment: For the record, in a pre- industrial society The average mortality is at around 35(ish) which would make your calculations way off.

Comment: I can barely remember that they didn't have had magic in pre-industrial society.

Comment: @Richard While average mortality was indeed in early middle age, people who lived to be old were still moderately old by our standards. It's just that there was a lot of attrition along the way.

Comment: That's true but the average generation was still only about 15-18 years.

Comment: I tend to see that comment as 'Generations' of men not take how long a man can be expected to live and times by 300.

Comment: @Richard - You're forgetting that the primary reason average lifespans were so low was the enormous infant mortality rates - most kids died before their 7th birthday.  If you survived childhood, you could expect to live to be 50, 60, or maybe even 70.  The risk wasn't dying at age 40, it was dying at age 5.  When 60-70% of people didn't live through childhood, the average lifespan was dragged down by infant mortality, not by adults dying when they were middle aged.

Comment: Gandalf says "300 **lives** of men, I have walked this earth". Not "generations" - "LIVES". Depending on which men he has in mind, a life might mean anywhere from 70 years (normal people) to 400 years (Numenorean royalty).  Certainly he began walking the earth when Numenor existed, so the possibility that he meant Numenorean lives can't be dismissed out of hand. Still, chances are Gandalf meant 70 years or so, which makes him roughly 21,000 years old. And we can't forget that as Numenorean blood is being watered down, lifespans are probably DECREASING. This is the age of myths, not history.

Comment: @Richard - the usually reliable [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Men) says that the average lifespan of Men in the First Age was c. 58 yrs; in the Second Age, c. 330 yrs; in the Third Age, c. 146 yrs.  The data comes from [this](http://lotrproject.com/statistics/#lifeexpectancy) site.

Comment: @WadCheber - Well that just makes no sense at all. And is almost certainly worthy of its own question...

Comment: @Richard I thought so too, but I don't know how/what to ask.

Comment: @Richard - if you help me with the phrasing, I'll ask the question.  I'm a bit groggy today and "What's up with human lifespans in Middle-earth?" is the best I can do.

Comment: @WadCheber - That was pretty much my thought on the subject. You might want to reference the Tolkien Gateway page and find out how they came up with those (very precise) figures.

Comment: @Richard - the stats come from the statistics section of the LotR project site, and are based on all characters for whom the relevant  figures exist.

Comment: @WadCheber - Named characters are hardly a good analogue for the "average" man in Middle Earth.