# Who is the oldest character in LotR trilogy?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Who is the oldest character in the trilogy, what is his role, race and powers?

Comment: *Just* the trilogy, or the related works like Silmarillion and Histories of Middle Earth?

Comment: And by "character" do you mean including the Valar and Maiar (who existed before the world) or not?

Comment: Let's give the user another day to check in and possibly reword, and if it's a hit-n-run *we* should reword it to re-open. I'm enjoying the discussion. It never occurred to me that such a "simple" question is anything but.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - I'd be more inclined to leave this one closed but ask a separate question (or series of separate questions) with tighter scope.

Comment: Fine by me, but the question sounds so simple that I love its elegance. Do what thou wilt. (cough cough, Merciful Release, cough) ;)

Comment: Also, book or movies?

Comment: See also the related questions http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50367/ Who or what is the oldest sentient being in Tolkien's lore? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/ Who's older: Treebeard or Tom Bombadil?

Comment: The question may be too broad, but the answer isn't:  Eru Iluvatar.